# Why react-navigation element not showing if using alignItems:"center"?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

When I'm using style property alignItems:"center" for parent element View which contains react-navigation component it shows me blank screen

But without this property everything works well just content is not centered

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import MainScreen from './screens/MainScreen';
import Main from './components/Main';

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Main: { screen: MainScreen }
    },
    { initialRouteName: 'Main' }
);

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default function App() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <AppNavigator />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',//there is the problem
        justifyContent: 'center',
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not considered as a good practice to style the component parent to your `AppNavigator`.

You should put all of your styling in each of your app screens, start by applying them to the main container of you view in `./screens/MainScreen.js`,

and remplace your app function with:

```js
export default function App() {
    return (
        <AppNavigator />
    );
}
```